# Convert SVG to XAML

Tags: graphics, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I tried InkScape & [XPS method](http://benpittoors.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/convert-svg-to-xaml/), but it doesn't give me correct XAML.

Can anyone please convert [this SVG](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9E70869A1583FA52!735) to WinRT compatible XAML ?

Comment: If you want people to do your work for you, you'll have more luck with the Amazon Mechanical Turk than here.

Comment: I've tried my ways but I failed that's why I asked.

Comment: Then show us what you've tried.

Comment: No need to show, you should believe me at least and not downvote. My 4.3K rep on SO is not funny thing. See Tim's thoughts. He believed me and gave me exact solution.

Comment: @Xyroid - it doesn't matter what your rep on SO is, your post is still worded as "do my work for me".  With that rep, you should know the etiquette of SO already.  And Tim answered properly, by telling you how to do it, and not doing it for you like you asked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at this and see if it works: https://gist.github.com/timheuer/6443390

Method (yes, superhack):

- Use Inkscape to save as PDF
- Rename the Filename extension from PDF to AI
- Use `Expression Design` to open AI document
- Export to Silverlight Canvas

Comment: Save as xaml with Inkscape (silverlight compatible) worked for me on Windows 8.1 (store app)

Comment: The current version of Inkscape now can export directly to XAML, no need to go via PDF, rename and blend import.

Comment: The current Inkscape saves the wrong XAML for me. It does a ViewBox containing a Canvas. I want a DrawingBrush instead. Using this method in the answer I imported into a Blend App, then clicked Tools -> Make VisualBrush Resource. Plugged that into a new ResourceDictionary and added "Stretch" property and removed "ViewBox" property.

Comment: +1 even though it is, as you say, a `superhack`.  One would think that by now there would be better ways. :(

Answer (score 16):

Using Inkscape 0.91 it's possible to open an SVG file and directly save as XAML.

Select *Microsoft XAML* file as the file type:

[image]

Note that in InkScape 1.3, XAML export was moved to [an extension](https://inkscape.gitlab.io/extensions/documentation/extensions/svg2xaml.html) and must be installed separately.

Comment: And Inkscape will give the option to make it compatible with Silverlight, too.

Comment: Looks like that feature has been removed. Looking at v1.3 and it's no longer there.

Comment: @RickStrahl ah I'm sorry to hear that. I'm on 1.1 which has the feature still.

Comment: @RickStrahl The XAML export has been rewritten  nad made as extension. https://inkscape.org/doc/release_notes/1.3/Inkscape_1.3.html

Comment: But it looks like the extension is currently not included in latest release - https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/8921)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [SvgToXaml](https://github.com/BerndK/SvgToXaml).

A simple and easy tool where you can convert SVG to XAML, and a built-in render/viewer of the SVG file.

Comment: Outputs SVGs as DrawingGroups instead of Canvases like the Inkscape method.

Comment: Can be used for batch conversion as well so maybe quicker than the Inkscape method

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment on the related answer, but I found it even easier to just open the `SVG` in `Inkscape`, copy and then paste it on `Expression Design`. Then select `Copy to XAML` (or `Ctrl + Shift + C`).

Comment: For those wondering `Expression Design` seems to be referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Design